# Div 100% height of viewport & second div 100% height of entire page

Tags: css

How can I have a div with height 100% filling the viewport AND a second div (positioned absolute) covering the entire page (a dropdown)?

More info: I have a div on my homepage containing a hero image. The div needs to fill the viewport. Below the hero div is more content. I have the following code:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; }
.hero { height: 100%; }
```

I would prefer to use `height:100%` than `height:100vh` because on tablets and phones (in Chrome) the viewport height changes when scrolling and in iOS Safari the bottom of the hero div is hidden behind the apps controls (bookmarks etc) when using `100vh`.

The above works fine for the hero image div. BUT I have a drop down menu/nav bar. The dropdown needs to have a height of the entire page, not just the viewport. The menu has an absolute position. If I set the height to 100% it only covers the viewport height, not the entire page. The same is true if I set `top:0;` and `bottom:0;`.

How can I do this? Thank you

First pic shows the hero div in blue with a height of the screen (minus the header). There is more content below the 'fold'.

Second pic show the drop down menu which should cover the entire height of the page. Hence the white drop down will have considerably more height than just the hero div.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;`

Comment: That doesn't work it is absolutely positioned in relation to the body and the body has a height of 100% i.e. top is the top of the screen and bottom is bottom of  the screen (not bottom of the page).

Comment: mm and why can't you add a wrapper div that wrap all of the page content and only has `position: relative;`?

Comment: Doesn't work because the hero div is then only as heigh as the content within it, not the height of the viewport

Comment: The nav bar has a height of 50px. On small devices the five options in the nav bar collapse into one hamburger icon. Then when clicked it reveals a full page drop down menu. Fairly standard stuff.

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually is asking, so please provide more info, maybe a screen shot or drawing, so we better understand what your issue is

Answer (score 0):

The inner element's height 100% means it will occupy its container. If you want to occupy the entire page, you have to use `top:0`, `left:0` and in JavaScript, use `innerElement.style.height=document.body.style.height;`

Comment: Sorry the example is slight more complicated. The nav bar has a height of 50px, and sits above the hero div. So the hero div actually has a height:calc(100% - 50px). Hence the nav bar is not inside the hero div.

Answer (score 0):

Previous snippet might not work
You should use `clientHeight`

```
innerElement.style.height=document.body.clientHeight
```

Comment: but the nav dropdown isn't inside the hero div. See comment above. But it is inside the body. Would this still work? I was hoping for a CSS solution as I don't know anything about JavaScript or how to implement it.

Comment: You have to read about using JS in HTML/CSS manipulations.  
You can provide a jsfiddle with an example, then me or other people could suggest a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'vh' and 'vw' instead:

- 100vh - 100 virtual height %
- 100vw - 100 virtua width %

Comment: In the opening post I try to state why I don't want to use vh. But I'll probably end up using it because it looks like the only CSS solution

Comment: You were wrong, vh is canvas height (part of the page you can see at the moment).

Comment: vh is the height of the viewport and as I tried to communicate in my opening post, on an iPhone the bottom of a hero div with 100vh is behind the iPhone/Safari controls (bookmarks, back arrow etc). This is a problem because the user can then not see (until  they scroll down) the down arrow I have at the bottom of the hero div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
function openMenu(){
   document.getElementById("ddl").style.display = "block";
}

function closeMenu(){
   document.getElementById("ddl").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body{ 
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; /*for test */
}

.menu{height: 50px;} /* first child of body */
.hero{
  flex: 1; 
  background-color:#4de6d0;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);   /*for test */
  }  /* second child of body */
.dropDown {
   position: absolute;
   min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
   top: 0;
   background-color:white;
   display: none;
   width: 80%;
   }
   .dropDown > div{
      height: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 60px;
      }
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="menu" onclick="openMenu()">Menu</div>
   <div class="hero"></div>
   <div class="dropDown" id="ddl">
      <div onclick="closeMenu()">Close</div>
      <div>Work</div>
      <div>About</div>
      <div>Services</div>
      <div>Ethics</div>
      <div>Contact</div>
   </div>
<body>
```

Finally I did not understand what you exactly want, But if you want the drop down is the height of screen you can change this property:

```
 min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

to this: `calc(100vh - 50px);`

In `.dropDown` styles

Comment: so that would give me the fullscreen hero div, but the drop down menu will only be as heigh as the body, which is 100%, which is the height of the screen. I want the drop down menu to cover / be as heigh as the entire page.

Comment: Looking at it, I'm not sure it helps. Once the body has height of 100% the height of the dropdown will also be 100% (of the viewport height) not the entire page.

Comment: No it isn't. If you set html and body to have a height of 100% and then the hero_div to have a height of 100%  the hero div is only as heigh as the screen, not the entire page. Same goes for the dropdown menu.

Comment: The body shouldn't have a fixed height. I've tried setting html, body { height:100% } and .hero_div { height:100%; } and the hero div has same height of screen, which is great, but then the dropdown's height is limited to the height of the screen. It doesn't cover entire page.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I've added two images

Comment: The hero image should be height of screen. And the drop down should be height of entire page.

Comment: And both the hero div and the drop down should use percentage, not vh

Comment: Your page needs at least one element to make the height. In my answer hero div made it. If you set `html, body, hero, {height: 100%;}` So 100% of what? 100% of 1000px or 100% of 2000px or ...?

Comment: If you set html, body, hero { height: 100% } the result is 100% of the screen height. Not the height of the entire page.

Comment: the hero div has the height of the screen. Not the height of the entire page.

Comment: **NO**. If you set html, body, hero { height: 100% } the hero image fills the screen which is great. But the dropdown with height 100% doesn't cover the entire page, just the height of the screen. As I said in the opening post, how is it possible, using percentage heights to have one div filling the screen and another filling the entire page.

Comment: As  I said in the opening post, is there anyway of doing this without using vh. Using percentage height on both hero div and the drop down?

Comment: Previously I answered this. Please read my first comment. You must have at least one real height element. (by **px** or **vh**).

Comment: So there is no way to have two divs with height 100%, one the height of the screen, the second the height of the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

From exhaustive research it doesn't seem possible to have one div with a height of 100% to fill the height of the screen and a second div with height 100% to cover the height of the enire page.